# How can I replace WITH inside a CREATE TRIGGER in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following piece of code that creates a trigger that pulls some info from any other row in the same table with the same `hash` as the newly added row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER if not exists tr 
after insert ON images 
BEGIN 

WITH a AS ( SELECT * FROM images WHERE hash = new.hash )
update images set 
categories = a.categories,
quality = a.quality,
ide = a.ide,
drawing = a.drawing,
ide_commentary = a.ide_commentary,
priority = a.priority
where rowid = new.rowid;

END
```

However, for some reason SQLite [doesn't support](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) doing this. The only way I can see of doing what I want seems to be making a separate select for each value that needs to be updated, like this:

```
categories = ( SELECT categories FROM images WHERE hash = new.hash ),
quality = ( SELECT quality FROM images WHERE hash = new.hash ),
etc.
```

but this is just terrible on every level. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: The latest SQLite version supports row values.

Comment: @CL Exactly what I was looking for (but didn't know the name of), thanks.